# Is there some way to put wordpress static pages in categories?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website that has a combination of Wordpress static pages and posts, but it is mostly static pages. I would like to use the Wordpress "categories" feature to organize these pages. So far I haven't figured out how to do this. Is there a plug-in or something? Failing that, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress, categories are for posts, not pages. If you want to create a "category" to organize your pages in, create a page with your category name. Then, if you want to place a page in that category, simply set the page's parent to the category page.

Comment: Gosh, I thought that was what you were going to say. The advantage of categories is that a page can be in multiple categories. A page can only have a single parent; Wordpress pages are not C++ classes...